Why is there color banding shown on Chrome when using an element with a color set in oklch?
I have a very simple demo page with the HTML:
<body style="margin:0">
    <div class="bg-purple" style="  background-color: oklch(43.34% 0.2575 284.05); height:80vh">
</body>


I have this simple demo page hosted here.
When viewed in Safari, Firefox and Arc the purple is a solid color. When viewed in Chrome (Version 124.0.6367.119 on MacOS) there is a lighter shade at the top, which changes size depending on screen size. .
I have tried putting the OKLCH in a conditional statement in CSS @supports (color: color(display-p3 1 1 1 / 1)), and setting a normal hex purple as well, but Chrome ignores the hex code and still tries to render the OKLCH color

I visited your demo link on a Chromebook running Chrome 123.0.6312.134, and there was no lighter shade on the top.
